# If you are dealt a hand of three cards from a conventional 52 card pack, what is the probability that your hand will include the Ace of Spades?

Tags: statistics

I have a statistics question:

If you are dealt a hand of three cards (without replacement) from a conventional 52 card pack, what is the probability that your hand will include the Ace of Spades?

My thoughts on it are that P(Ace of Spades) = (3/52) because there is only one ace of spades in the card. However, given that there is no replacement, should the answer not be (1/52)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\frac1{52}$ would be the answer if you were only dealt one card.  Since you were dealt three, the answer will be higher than that.  What made you think of $\frac3{52}$ (which is indeed correct)?

Comment: I thought of 3/52 because I would calculate: (1/52) x (1/52) x (1/52). However, because the cards are not replaced, I don't think that would actually make sense.

Comment: $\frac1{52} \times \frac1{52} \times \frac1{52} \not = \frac3{52}$ but $\frac1{52} + \frac1{52} + \frac1{52} = \frac3{52}$.  So you need an argument for this addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the hand is dealt without replacement that we can say the probability is $\frac{3}{52}$ right off the bat. This is because since the position of the Ace of Spades does not matter, we can consider the 3 cards to have been dealt all at the same time. As a sanity check:

To calculate the probability that the hand includes the Ace of Spades, we can calculate the probability that the hand does **not** contain the Ace of Spades and subtract that from 1.

$P(\text{First card not Ace of Spades})=\frac{51}{52}$

$P(\text{Second card not Ace of Spades|First card was not})=\frac{50}{51}$

$P(\text{Third card not Ace of Spades|First and second were not})=\frac{49}{50}$

So $P(\text{Ace of Spades})=1-\frac{51}{52}\frac{50}{51}\frac{49}{50}=\frac{3}{52}$

Had we allowed replacement, the probability would have been $1-\left(\frac{51}{52}\right)^3$ which includes the possibilities of having multiple Ace of Spades in the hand.

Comment: Alternatively, the first card dealt could be the Ace of Spades, or the second, or the third. Without replacement these are mutually exclusive so you can sum the three probabilities of $\frac1{52}$

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes you are correct, I'll change that now